# ES6 import duplicates?

Tags: javascript, module, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to keep my code (server and client side) as modular as possible and this requires a lot of importing and exporting, however I have an unanswered question.

I tried to search from here, I read topical blog posts and even watched few YT videos, but it's still not fully explained. I would love to avoid making this mistake right now and avoid rewriting my logic later.

---

**File1**

```
import React from 'react';

// do something
```

**File2**

```
import React from 'react';

// do something else
```

**File3**

```
import File1 from './file1';
import File2 from './file2';

// do something with both
```

---

- Is it smart enough? Can I import same
  module as much as I want and it imports it only once?
- What if I need to `import React` to **File3** too? Is it still smart enough to handle this situation?

I'm using Node, Babel and Webpack.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

When you import a module through Node (and by extension, Webpack, as it effectively follows the same rules when it comes to module resolution), the code in the file is executed once, then the resulting exports are cached. This means that in both of your files, `React` will be a reference to the same object. So effectively your assumption is correct - Webpack is indeed smart enough to not execute React's full source code file every time you import it.

You can test this for yourself pretty easily - add a `console.log()` to a module that's imported in multiple places within your app (making sure it's not in a function or anything else that would defer its execution). You'll see that the log only happens once, rather than once per import!

**Update:** It's also worth noting that [the spec for ES2015 modules](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-hostresolveimportedmodule) effectively lists this as a requirement for any implementation too:

> This operation must be idempotent if it completes normally. Each time it is called with a specific `referencingModule, specifier` pair as arguments it must return the same Module Record instance.

Comment: I like the logic of your test design!